# Web3.py - how to use abi in python when solc doesn't work

Tags: contract-invocation, web3.py

I have a smart contract that I deployed to the Ropsten test network with truffle (using Javascript).  I want to be able to send transactions to it from my server, which is written in Python.  I've been trying to follow: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.contract

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import json

provider = HTTPProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/<Redacted Key>')
w3 = Web3(provider)
assert w3.isConnected()

pdb.set_trace()
abi = str(<Here I am pasting my abi in.  How should I do this, since I didn't build the contract in Python?>
escrow = w3.eth.contract(address='0x8850259566e9d03a1524e35687db2c78d4003409', abi=abi)
```

... When I get to this line, the program crashes:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/eth.py", line 351, in contract
    ContractFactory = ContractFactoryClass.factory(self.web3, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 225, in factory
    normalizers=normalizers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/utils/datatypes.py", line 36, in __new__
    namespace)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 236, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 22, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/web3/utils/formatters.py", line 69, in apply_formatters_to_dict
    raise type(exc)("Could not format value %r as field %r" % (item, key)) from exc
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'doc' and 'pos'
```

Comment: It looks like there should be another part of the exception, with the message `"Could not format value ... as field ..."`. Can you add that trace to the question, and the version of web3.py that you are using?

Comment: I was able to get some help on the web3.py githubg page.  Now I can compile the smart contract, but I can't get the abi:

(let me know if I should close this issue or if you have any feedback: https://github.com/ethereum/py-solc/issues/49)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide the abi as a dictionary, not as a string. Since the ABI is json encoded, you need to parse it with `json.loads` or similar.

You should also read it directly from the contract json file that is generated by truffle. This makes sure you don't accidentally use an old ABI. Here is what I do:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import json

with open("build/Contracts/YourContract.json") as f:
    info_json = json.load(f)
abi = info_json["abi"]

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://..."))
escrow = w3.eth.contract(address='0x8850259566e9d03a1524e35687db2c78d4003409', abi=abi)
```

Comment: I was able to get this working by downgrading solc from 0.4.19 to 0.4.17

Comment: Huh, good to know. Do you know what the specific problem with the new version was?

Comment: I wish I did :(